# How to Re Active onClick Listener in onResume Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have created an Activity named `BaseNavigationActivity` that creates`NavigationDrawer`. All other activities are extending from this activity. It works fine,open the drawer on button click.

But when i go into another activity, and come back to previous Activity. The button stops working. Although visually button is still there, and if i click and drag from left side, it opens the `Drawer Layout`

When i debug it, i found out that it calls `onRestart()` and `onResume()` methods, but there is no code written in these method.

So do i need to add the code there as well?  or is there any way to implement `onClickListner` in `onRestart()` and `onResume()` of Activity

**onCreate()**

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
headerLayout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.header_layout);
btnOpenDrawer= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_openDrawer);
homeLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_layout);


btnOpenDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

    }
});


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

}
```

Comment: Did my suggestion fix your problem?

Comment: No it didn't,  adding elements to `onResume` caused problems

Comment: What problems? Can you post a logcat if you got crashes?

Answer (score 2):

**Create class level ClickListener like *onClickListener* and Use it wherever you want.**

```
  // Activate Listener
        myView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        // DeActivate Listener
        myView.setOnClickListener(null);

// Listener
View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks..what is myView is refering to?

Comment: myView is view on which you wih to apply click listener, in your case its btnOpenDrawer.

Comment: This is what i have done, I added `onClickListener` on class level, and in `OnCreate`I assigned it to `btnDrawer.setOnClickListener(onClickListener)`. It worked fine for the first activity, but the same problem occurs when i go back to the  previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the error is that you set your OnClickListener in the onCreate Method. The OnClickListener only gets set when you create the activity. When you switch to your second activity, the OnClickListener will get overwritten and when you go back to your first activity the OnClickListener will not be set, because the first activity was already created, and only onResume will get called.

Try to move your code from the onCreate to onResume, so the listener will get set every time the activity is moving back to the front.